# Getting next upcoming day from given days array comparing toady C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I got an array of days,  have to select next upcoming day by comparing today,
here is my code snippet-

```
private string GetUpcomingDeliveryDay(string today, ModelSetting ObjModelSetting)
{
    //string today = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString(); //Tuesday
    // daysOfDeliveries = ("Monday","Friday")
    string[] daysOfDeliveries = Convert.ToString(ObjModelSetting.DeliveryDays).Split(',');
    string nextDelivery = string.Empty;

    return nextDelivery;
}
```

ex. if today is Monday and it is present in the array then it should return Monday else upcoming closest day from that array.

I never worked on days and date section before so it's getting harder for me.
 thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `daysOfDeliveries` in `DaysOfWeek` format then it will be easy. So if it is in `string` format first you need to convert it to `Enum.DaysOfWeek`. The rest will be a simple comparison:

```
var days = daysOfDeliveries.Select(x => (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), x)).ToArray();
DayOfWeek today = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
var nextDelivery = days.Where(x => x >= today).FirstOrDefault();
```

please make sure that the strings in `daysOfDeliveries` comply with the Enum names.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
private static string GetUpcomingDeliveryDay(string today, string[] days) 
{
    if (days.Length == 0)
    {
        return string.Empty;    
    }

    if (days.Any(x => x == today.ToString())) 
    {
        return today;   
    }

    var day = string.Empty;
    var allDays = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek));
    var i = Array.IndexOf(allDays, Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), today));

    while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(day))
    {
        i++;

        if (i >= allDays.Length) 
        {
            i = 0;  
        }

        if (days.Any(x => x == allDays.GetValue(i).ToString()))
        {
            day = allDays.GetValue(i).ToString();
        }
    }

    return day;
}
```